# I search a PNP array IC

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, components, logic-gates, pnp

i have a print where i need like 8 PNP transistors. They are all connected the same: The Emitter is connected to VCC, the Base is connected to a GPIO and a Pullup and the Collector is connected to some LED. 
The chip i want has an Input for each Transistor which connects to the Base, an Output for each Transistor, which connects to the Collecter and one pin which shares all the Emitters. Ideally it also has a Pullup on every Base.

I think the ULN series is something similar with NPN or a Darlington pair, but not sure.

I'v drawn a small sketch, on how the Chip could look like:

[image]

Comment: So... you're asking us to find you a chip based on a drawing you made? Am I getting that right?

Comment: @RonBeyer basically... yeah

Comment: @Ron, the question may be a bit more generic. We see the ULN2003 used everywhere. I don't think I've ever seen an example of a PNP version. In search non-English language may be an issue. I find it difficult to find the right search sometimes terms and I speak English.

Comment: @Transistor Possibly, the search term here should be "PNP array", [Digikey lists several](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-arrays/277?k=pnp+array&k=&pkeyword=pnp+array&sv=0&pv74=203851&sf=0&FV=-8%7C277&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25).

Comment: @Transistor i'm currently looking at the UDN2981... i think this one might be the chip im searching for. I'm just not sure about the darlington array which they added after the PNP BJP.

Comment: @Felix, I am not familiar with them. The datasheet is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend searching on DigiKey.com. From my search, There is an IC called MMPQ2907A which consists of an array of 4 pnp transistors. If you needed 8 then you just get two ICs. Here you’d externally connect your pull-up resistors and load. 
Note that this is one of many parts available and this is just an example.

Comment: Yeah, this IC would work. I just hoped there is one in something like a SOP16 Footprint, where there are 7 Transistors in there with the common Emitter...